# how to ignore the backslash in expect script

Tags: linux, windows, tcl, expect, scp

I create the following script (expect under ksh ) ,

in order to copy the file data.txt from Linux machine to windows machine

scp process will be automatic by expect , so password question will be answered by expect

the problem is that expect can’t ignore the "\" backslash from the following line

```
   spawn  scp   /tmp/data.txt  ADMIN@192.9.200.17:'c:\'
```

so from output I see that expect send the line without the "\" backslash

what need to change in my syntax/script so expect will ignore the backslash ?

my script

```
  #!/bin/ksh




 PASSORD=secret123


 SCP=`cat << EOF
 set timeout -1


spawn  scp   /var/tmp/data.txt  ADMIN@192.9.200.17:'c:\'
       expect {
                 ")?"   { send "yes\r"  ;          exp_continue  }                                
                 word:  {send $PASSORD\r}
              }
  expect eof
  EOF`



  expect -c  "$SCP"
```

.

results ( output )

```
 spawn scp /var/tmp/data.txt ADMIN@192.9.200.17:'c:'
 gcs@198.202.183.97's password: 
 scp: c:: Error opening file: The requested operation failed.
 Killed by signal 1.
```

Comment: Try using 'c:/' instead, might evaluate to the same path.

Comment: yes you right its work now thx allot

Comment: Answer this , and I will Vote ,

Comment: Mark my response as the answer so that other users know what the solution is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `spawn  scp   /tmp/data.txt  ADMIN@192.9.200.17:'c:/'` instead as it should evaluate to the same path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `\`.

Try

```
spawn  scp   /tmp/data.txt  ADMIN@192.9.200.17:'c:\\'
```

Comment: What is the output you get when you run the script? Can you `scp` to the Windows box from the shell (not within the expect script)?

Comment: Then probably the expect script is not the problem. Your Windows box might not an SSH/SCP server running